# How to typeset superscript IPA characters

Tags: symbols, linguistics, tipa

I'm using TIPA and I'm trying to do something like this:

```
\textipa{/bI"wIl.d@r.IN/}
```

Which works, but I want the `@` character to be an upper index. How do I do this?

I've tried this

```
\textipa{/bI"wIl.d}^{\textipa{@}}\textipa{r.IN/}
```

but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the `tipa` package but you can use the `\textsuperscript` command for typesetting superscript in text (not math) mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipa}
\begin{document}
\textipa{/bI"wIl.d\textsuperscript{@}r.IN/}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

According to the documentation of TIPA, you can also use the command `\super` which is an abbreviated form of `\textsuperscript`. Like `\textipa{t\super{h} k\super{w}
  a\super{bc} a\super{b\super{c}}}`.